# How to load Data Warehouse using ODI?

Tags: data-warehouse, oracle-data-integrator, fact-table

After searching in the web about how to use ODI to extract, load and transform data in the Data Warehouse, i'm still confused about one step.
After loading the tables in the Staging area, and doing the mapping to load the data, how can we in the second step load data in a datawarehouse(fact and dimension tables)?

Thank you.

Comment: Actually in most cases, you create a mapping from Source to Target and ODI does the staging steps in KM. You won't need to thin much about staging. That's why Oracle call it as an E-LT Tool.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification!